# Word Automation Service No longer working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, word-automation

Hi we have been round and round with this for a few days.

The service was fine and the workflow using it fine - but has stopped for some reason..

We have restarted the servers a few times, recreated the word automation services - stopped/started tried some debugging but not getting anywhere.

Our latest ULS logs say...

```
There is an uninitialized worker that took too long to connect back. [Worker Guid: 8708ef8a-08af-401d-81d5-699701f2966a]. Starting a new process


AppWorker:b451069b-7a70-42a7-a73c-eac21a2c16d7 process creation failed Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Failed to launch sandbox process    
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Security.Sandbox.CreateSandboxedProcess(SandboxedProcessArgs args)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.RequestPipe.BaseSandboxedWorker.CreateSandBoxedProcess(String appServerHostExe, String workingDir, String arguments, UInt32 quotaCommittedMemory, UInt32 userTimeLimitInMilliSeconds)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Framework.AppWorker.Start(String appServerHostExe, String convertingServiceUri, IWorkerDescription workerDescription)
```

--

That's about it.
Has any got any ideas, there is an error code of 10 in the Items database but not much indication of how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is one that be solved by the

```
$sp = Get-SPServiceApplication | where {$_.TypeName.Equals("Word Automation Services")}
$sp.DisableSandbox = $true
$sp.Update()
```

Then a stop/start of the word process.